# My array becomes empty in the next elsif loop but still holds its value if used outside the loops

Tags: arrays, loops, perl

I am trying to use an array between two elsif loops, but the array output returns nothing if I use it inside the second loop. However, if I use the same array outside the loops it works. Ex:

```
while (<FH>){
    if(condition1){
        do this;
        do that;
    }
    elsif(condition2){
        push (@arr, $_);
    }
    elsif(condition3){
        print @arr;
    }
}
```

The code above would not print anything for me in the output.

But, if I use the code below, it prints the array elements correctly.

```
while (<FH>){
    if(condition1){
        do this;
        do that;
    }
    elsif(condition2){
        push (@arr, $_);
    }
    elsif(condition3){
        next;
    }
}
print @arr;
```

Can someone explain me why is this happening or can you point me to a thread which might have already discussed this issue? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Posting my actual code here for a better understanding as requested in the comments section.

```
while(<USER_INPUT>){
    if ($_=~ /(.*) =\n/ ){
        print "\nFormat not correct on line $. of input file. Exiting script\n";
        exit;
    }
    elsif ($_=~ /(.*) =\s+\n/ ){
        print "\nFormat not correct on line $. of input file. Exiting script\n";
        exit;
    }
    elsif ($_=~ /(.*) = \s+(.*)/ ){
        print "\nFormat not correct on line $. of input file. Exiting script\n";
        exit;
    }
    elsif ($_=~ /^TASK_CELL_NAME\|VALUE = (.*)/ ){
        $n=0;
        $cell_name=$1;
        chomp $cell_name;
    }
    elsif ($_=~ /^TASK\|VALUE = (.*)/ ){
        $task=$1;
        chomp $task;
        $rpl= 'new_replay_files/'.$cell_name.'_'.$task.'_calibre.qvi_replay';
        $ref = $ref_dir.'/'.$task.'_calibre.qvi_replay';
    }
    elsif ($_=~ /^(.*)\|VALUE = (.*)/ ){
        $line=$_;
        $var=$1;
        push (@lines, $line);
        push (@vars, $var);
        $n ++ ;
    }

    elsif ($_=~ /^\s*$/ || $_=~ /^\n/){
        open(REF, "<$ref")  || print "\n!!!ERROR OPENING $ref.!!!\n";
        open(OUT, ">$rpl")  || print "\n!!!ERROR OPENING $rpl.!!!\n";

        foreach(@vars){

            while (<REF>){
                if ($_=~ /^(.*)\|VALUE = (.*)/ ){
                    $match_line=$_;
                    $match_var=$1;
                    $lines= \@lines;
                    if(grep( /$match_var/, @vars )){
                        s/$match_line/$lines->[$count]/g;
                        print OUT;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    s/\$CELL/$cell_name/g;
                    print OUT;
                }
                $count ++ ;
            }
        }
        close REF;
        close OUT;
    }

}

close USER_INPUT;
```

The USER_INPUT file looks like this:

```
TASK_CELL_NAME|VALUE = AAA
TASK|VALUE = lvs
TASK_VERSION|VALUE = 000
CHIP_PKG_TYPE|VALUE = 111

TASK_CELL_NAME|VALUE = BBB
TASK|VALUE = lvs
TASK_VERSION|VALUE = 222
CHIP_PKG_TYPE|VALUE = 333

TASK_CELL_NAME|VALUE = CCC
TASK|VALUE = lvs
TASK_VERSION|VALUE = 444
CHIP_PKG_TYPE|VALUE = 555
```

Comment: I think you're struggling with basic understanding of conditionals. To refute that it's best to describe in your own words how desired algorithm works.

Comment: Without seeing some sample data and your actual conditions, it's impossible to know what is going on here.

Comment: @Сухой27, the code I posted is basically a small gist. In reality, I am trying to do a lot more in condition3 with the array. Should I post that code, if it helps better? Yes- you could say I am struggling with understanding this, not a regular programmer who's expert in perl :) Thanks for sharing your time.

Comment: The most obvious explanation for what you're seeing is that `condition3` is never true.

Comment: @DaveCross I have updated my actual code.

Comment: Re "*the code I posted is basically a small gist*", It's really not. The problem you describe isn't exhibited by your pseudocode, so it's not the gist of the issue.

Comment: Re "*I have updated my actual code.*", That's neither runnable nor minimal. Please provide something that actually demonstrates the problem, and does so with minimal code. This includes providing any necessary data needed to replicate the problem. (Right now, even after making changes to open `USER_INPUT`, it just outputs a bunch of ```ERROR OPENING``` messages.)

Comment: Finally, you should ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`. I strongly hesitate to look at code that doesn't.

Comment: @ikegami : posted the final code that worked for me after debug. Thanks for your time. I have added all the necessary strict and warnings.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me finally. Thank you for finding out time to check out my question and comment

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#########################################################################################################################################################################################

my $num_args = $#ARGV +1 ;
if ($num_args != 0) 
{

   print "\nUsage: perl replay_file_changes.pl\n";
   exit;
}

#########################################################################################################################################################################################


#########################################################################################################################################################################################

print "\nPLEASE SPECIFY INPUT FILE\n";
my $ip_file = <>;
chomp $ip_file ;
if (-e $ip_file){
    }
else{
    print "\n$ip_file IS NOT FOUND\n";
    exit;
    }
print "\nPLEASE SPECIFY REFERENCE FILES DIRECTORY\n";
my $ref_dir = <>;
chomp $ref_dir ;
if (-d $ref_dir){
    }
else{
    print "\n$ref_dir IS NOT FOUND\n";
    exit;
    }
#########################################################################################################################################################################################






#########################################################################################################################################################################################



`rm -rf new_replay_files`;
`mkdir new_replay_files`;
my @lines=();
my @vars=();
my $cell_name;
my $rpl;
my $ref;
my $task;

open(USER_INPUT, "<$ip_file")  || die "\n!!!ERROR OPENING INPUT FILE. EXITING SCRIPT!!!\n";


while(<USER_INPUT>){
                  if ($_=~ /(.*) =\n/ ){
                                print "\nFormat not correct on line $. of input file. Exiting script\n";
                                exit;
                               }
                  elsif ($_=~ /(.*) =\s+\n/ ){
                                  print "\nFormat not correct on line $. of input file. Exiting script\n";
                                  exit;
                                 }
                  elsif ($_=~ /(.*) = \s+(.*)/ ){
                                     print "\nFormat not correct on line $. of input file. Exiting script\n";
                                     exit;
                                    }
                  elsif ($_=~ /^TASK_CELL_NAME\|VALUE = (.*)/ ){
                                            $cell_name=$1;
                                            chomp $cell_name;
                                           }
                  elsif ($_=~ /^TASK\|VALUE = (.*)/ ){
                                      $task=$1;
                                      chomp $task;
                                      $rpl= 'new_replay_files/'.$cell_name.'_'.$task.'_calibre.qvi_replay';
                                      $ref = $ref_dir.'/'.$task.'_calibre.qvi_replay';
                                         }
                  elsif ($_=~ /^(.*)\|VALUE = (.*)/ ){                
                                          my $line=$_;
                              my $var=$1;
                              push (@lines, $line);
                              push (@vars, $var);
                              }

              elsif ($_=~ /^\s*$/ || $_=~ /^\n/){



                               open(REF, "<$ref")  || print "\n!!!ERROR OPENING $ref.!!!\n";
                                   open(OUT, ">$rpl")  || print "\n!!!ERROR OPENING $rpl.!!!\n";
                               while (<REF>){

                                         if ($_=~ /^(.*)\|VALUE = (.*)/ ){
                                                         my $match_line=$_;
                                                         my $match_var=$1;
                                                         if(grep( /^$match_var$/, @vars )){
                                                                           foreach (@lines)
                                                                       {
                                                                        if($_=~ /^$match_var\|VALUE = (.*)/ )
                                                                        {           
                                                                             my $replace_line=$_;
                                                                         print OUT "$replace_line";
                                                                            }
                                                                       }
                                                                       }
                                                    else{
                                                            s/\$CELL/$cell_name/g;
                                                            print OUT;
                                                                }
                                                    }
                                    else{
                                             s/\$CELL/$cell_name/g;
                                             print OUT;
                                             }

                                        } 
                                 }
           close REF;
           close OUT;

        }


close USER_INPUT;

#########################################################################################################################################################################################
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more convenient to write `die "$ip_file IS NOT FOUND" unless -e $ip_file` and `die "$ref_dir IS NOT FOUND" unless -d $ref_dir`?

Comment: Why not to use `while(<USER_INPUT>) { chomp; ....` instead _sprinkling_ the code with `chomp` in each `elsif`?

Comment: You try to `open(REF, "<$ref") || ....`, if it fails to open you print a message and still try to read from file which you was not able to open? Same situation with `open(OUT, ">$rpl") || ...`, print a  message if you can not open output file and still you try to print into it?

Comment: @Gordon: This answer would be a lot more useful if you added some explanation of the problems you have fixed.